# AES 256 ofb encryption/decryption not working with Openssl3.0

Tags: c++, encryption, openssl, encryption-symmetric

Currently we are using openssl1.1 for a file encryption/decryption.

We are facing a problem when we migrate to opensl3.0.

Below is the code flow used to encrypt the file.

```
    // Set up the encryption context
    const EVP_CIPHER *cipher = EVP_aes_256_cbc(); // Using AES 256 in CBC mode
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_new();
    EVP_EncryptInit_ex(ctx, cipher, nullptr, (const unsigned char *)key.c_str(), null);
    // Encrypt the data    
    int len;
    unsigned char buffer[1024];
    EVP_EncryptUpdate(ctx,buffer,&len,(const unsigned char *)plaintext.c_str(), plaintext.length());  
    ciphertext.insert(ciphertext.end(), buffer, buffer + len);
    // Finalize the encryption
    EVP_EncryptFinal_ex(ctx, buffer, &len);
    ciphertext.insert(ciphertext.end(), buffer, buffer + len);
    // Clean up
    EVP_CIPHER_CTX_free(ctx);
```

And in a similar way we have done the decryption also.

The same code is not working with openssl3.0, we identified that passing a valid IV instead of NULL is working fine in openssl3.0.

We understand that IV should be a random number, but passing null was working fine in openssl1.0.

Is there anything changed in openssl3.0 related to IV ?

We tried using valid IV instead of null, it is working fine.

Comment: So, use a valid IV? Problem solved?

Comment: Yes it work fine but i have understand what is changed in openssl between 1.0 to 3.0?
openssl document does not mention what will be the behavior if we pass NULL for IV.

Comment: OpenSSL does not have a reputation for having well-written documentation. What exactly is the information you're looking for? What would this documentation help you do, specifically? This worked, in some mysterious way in OpenSSL 1.0, it doesn't work in OpenSSL 3.0, what would change if, somewhere, the exact documentation of what OpenSSL 1.0 did, in this case, was uncovered?

Comment: during our implementation with openssl1.0 we have noticed in some documentation it is mentioned that if IV is null,  default value will be taken for IV and proceed with encryption/decryption.

Comment: not able to find that old documentation and need to understand why the same logic is not working in 3.0, because it will break our backward compatibility (if user encrypted the file with old implementation IV null, we will not be able to decrypt using new implementation).
We have this requirement that file encrypted with openssl1.0 should be decrypted using openssl3.0. Underlying Encryption algo will not change, if we provide the same key which is used for encryption it should decrypt the file across the openssl version

Comment: In that case, the fastest course of action is to download the source to OpenSSL 1.0 and read it. See what it does. Where it gets the IV, if it's NULL. My guess would be if the IV is specified as NULL it uses some built-in default. So, grab it, and use it yourself with OpenSSL 3.0. Read the source code.

Comment: I read the source of openssl1.0 and find that if IV is passed as NULL in EVP_EncryptInit_ex (), then it will take the default value of IV as 0 internally. I passed the same parameter in EVP_EncryptInit_ex () and it is working.
unsigned char default_iv[16] = { 0 };
EVP_DecryptInit_ex(m_pEVP_CTX, EVP_aes_256_ofb(), NULL, key, default_iv)
with the above fix my backward compability issue is fixed now .